# How can I join five tables in one table?

Tags: database, oracle, join

I have 5 tables which are devices logs, tables are the same, just divided by month, you need to glue them into one table and join it to the primary key with DEVICES_ACTIVE.

```
     1. Table DEVICES_ACTIVE
         DEVICE_ID  NUMBER(38,0)    PK

     2. Table DJ_05_2014
        DEVICE_ID NUMBER(38,0) PK
        START TIMESTAMP
        STOP TIMESTAMP

     3. Table DJ_06_2014
        DEVICE_ID NUMBER(38,0) PK
        START TIMESTAMP
        STOP TIMESTAMP

     4. Table DJ_07_2014
        DEVICE_ID NUMBER(38,0) PK
        START TIMESTAMP
        STOP TIMESTAMP
......................
```

Comment: can you show some data and the expected result?

Comment: Can you show us your effort? What have you done so far? What errors did you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ...
  from devices_active
  join (select ... from dj_07_2014 union all
        select ... from dj_06_2014 union all
        select ... from dj_05_2014
       ) using(device_id);
```